# use of unresolved identifier error when trying to make instance of a class

Tags: ios, xcode, class, swift

Im new to swift and having a simple problem - 
I made the following class 
import Foundation

```
class UserIdWithScore: NSObject {

   let userId: String
   let score: String

    init (userId: String, userScore: String) {
      self.userId = userId
      self.userScore = userScore
      super.init()
    }
```

then Im trying to make an instance of that class from another class

```
  class otherClass : SimpleCommand
     var usersIdAndScore = [UserIdWithScore()]
```

I get the following error - 'use of unresolved identifier 'UserIdWithScore'
whats weird is that Xcode help me finish my line for UserIdWithScore .. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has to be

```
var usersIdAndScore = [UserIdWithScore]()
```

Comment: but I want it to be an array of UserIdWithScore

Comment: then it has to be `[UserIdWithScore]()`

Comment: @AndreSlotta calling `[UserIdWithScore]()` will make an empty array, calling `[UserIdWithScore()]` will make an array with 1 var in it, please see @Phillip Mills answer

Comment: @AvielGross i see that answer but that is not what he was asking for, is it?

Comment: I up voted.. and i need to wait 3 min to approve the answer for some reson

Comment: @AndreSlotta your solution will leave him with an empty array of type `UserIdWithScore`. If this is the expected result then thats good, I assumed from the question that he is trying to create an array with an initial single value of type `UserIdWithScore`...

Answer (score 1):

Your initializer has two parameters.  Try something like:

```
var usersIdAndScore = [UserIdWithScore(userId: "Me", userScore: "5")]
```

Or create an empty initializer that supplies default values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a default initializer in your class `UserIdWithScore`. Instead you are initializing the class with two params `(userId: String, userScore: String)`

So call, `var usersIdAndScore = [UserIdWithScore(userId: "userId_String", userScore: "userscore_string")]`

or add the following initializer in your class

```
init() {
    // perform some initialization here
}
```